# re.findall in Python 3

Tags: python, regex, web

I wanted to use the function re.findall(), which searches through a webpage for a certain pattern:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import re


url = Request('http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/products/#sortField=oi&sortAsc=false&venues=3&page=1&cleared=1&group=1', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/20.0.1'})
webpage = urlopen(url).read()

findrows = re.compile('<td class="cmeTableCenter">(.*)</td>')
row_array = re.findall(findrows, webpage) #ERROR HERE
```

I get an error:

```
TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

Comment: `row_array = findrows.findall(webpage)`

Comment: I still get the same errir

Comment: The `webpage` variable is NOT `str`, it has the type `bytes` so you need to decode it first `webpage.decode('utf-8')`

Comment: I would use BeautifulSoup for this problem. Regex and HTML don't mix well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`urllib.request.urlopen` returns a `bytes` object, not a (Unicode) string. You should decode it before trying to match anything. For example, if you know your page is in UTF-8:

```
webpage = urlopen(url).read().decode('utf8')
```

Better HTTP libraries will automatically do this for you, but determining the right encoding isn't always trivial or even possible, so Python's standard library doesn't.

Another option is to use a `bytes` regex instead:

```
findrows = re.compile(b'<td class="cmeTableCenter">(.*)</td>')
```

This is useful if you don't know the encoding either and don't mind working with `bytes` objects throughout your code.

Comment: If I wanted to copy information from the provided website in between tags <tr class="- bandingOn"> [rows of info.] </td>, would this work? findrows = re.compile('<tr class="- bandingOn>(.*?)</tr>') --> uses regex

Answer (score 2):

You need to decode the bytes object first:

```
data = urlopen(url).read()
webpage = data.decode('utf-8')  #converts `bytes` to `str`
findrows.findall(webpage)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative you can compile a bytes regexp:

```
re.compile(b"yourpatternhere")
```